# Heroku outgoing sockets + ip changes

Tags: heroku

We're evaluating Heroku, and would appreciate hints on whether a Heroku-hosted application could open outgoing TCP sockets, towards our old legacy server. This legacy server has a home-made TCP protocol.

1. Is there any limitation such outgoing sockets, or other Heroku-related warnings on their behavior. E.g. currently we rely on a long-lasting communication channel - would Heroku cut them off after a while?
2. As mentioned, we'd prefer our socket to remain open for a while. But do I understand correctly that Heroku might arbitrarily switch the dyno's physical location (and thus, IP), which would cut off my connection? Is such a case, can I get some 'callback' from Heroku (I could find other workarounds, but a callback would save me time).

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

You are not limited in terms of making connections outward from the Heroku dyno, which resides on a shared EC2 instance.

There's nothing to prevent longer running connections (in fact, you are likely to have many pooled, persistent connections to databases and other services).  However, dynos are restarted at least once a day, so you will want to be able to reconnect and manage dynos coming up and down.

Dynos are arbitrarily provisioned for each deploy of your application.  You have no idea what EC2 instances your dyno will be running on.  So, the set of source IP addresses is random and shifts over time.  If you want to authenticate incoming connections, you will need to use other methods (like a username/password, certificates, etc).

Comment: thanks for this detailed reply. Just one clarification please: is there any callback through which Heroku can warn my application that its dyno was moved? On such a callback I could restart my connection pools, etc. Admittedly it's "nice to have" and not a showstopper. Thanks again

Comment: There are no callbacks for this.  The event you need to use is your application being stopped/started.  Your application will be restarted at least once a day.  Every time the application starts you should plan as if it's on a new dyno.

Comment: In your case, there is no way to "register" dynos in a meaningful way - the life cycle is too short and you can't connect back to them from the outside.  It's better to have each instance of your application phone-home to whatever services you're using and assume the lifetime of the dyno is the lifetime of the connection.