# Is it possible to establish a websocket connection between Heroku app and another webserver?

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

I'm wondering if this is possible. Websockets between client and server - ok, but can a Heroku hosted Node JS app establish a WS(S) connection with another server?

Comment: Why do you say it seems impossible? Making requests to other servers is done all the time from servers.  What port are you using?

Comment: It sure looks possible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683117/heroku-outgoing-sockets-ip-changes) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces).  Search for "outbound" in those pages.

Comment: Well - I tried. It didn't work for me. That's why I asked. However, thanks for chiming in, I don't need that any longer.